# Restarting socket.io on the clientside

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I'm using angularjs to build a single page app - I emit one message socket onto connections open for guests and users, and other to specific users.

Hence I need the socket to know whether to initialise the connection for a user or guest. As I'm using angular, I do not refresh the page when the user logs in, subsequently until the page is refreshed, the user does not receive their personal socket io notifications. (Too much info? Apologies!)

**Simple question** - How can I replicate what happens with socket io on a page refresh (restart it) programatically, preferably from the client side.

Tried this

```
restart: function(){
    socket.disconnect();
    window.socket = io.connect();
}
```

and it didn't work (only appears to call the on disconnect function, not actually restart the connection), can't seem to find any other solution!

Answer (score 0):

I used `WebSocket`:

Here is snippets of code that worked for me:

```
function startSocket() 
        {

            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
                ws = new WebSocket("%%WEBSOCKET_URL%%");



                // Called when the websocket is opened
                ws.onopen = function()
                {
                   /* .... */
                };

                // Called when the websocket receives data
                ws.onmessage = function(evt) 
                { 
                    /* .... */
                    //dataTableDefault.push(evt.data);                         
                };

                // Called when the websocket is closed
                ws.onclose = function() { 

                };
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Browser doesn't support WebSockets!");
            }
        }

function stopSocket() 
        {

            try {
                ws.onopen = null;
                ws.onmessage = null;
                ws.onclose = null;
                ws.onerror = null;

                ws.close(); 

            } catch (e) {
                console.log('try/catch around location update'+e);
            }

        }
```

Hope it will help,